# issue in setting up cucukoo in ubuntu. error is: 'python' has no installation candidate. error ss attached

Tags: ubuntu, cuckoo

[error shows 'python' has no installation candidate. I have installed the previous version but the error is not resolving](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D4y2r.png)

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Ubuntu 18.04? Newer versions of Ubuntu deprecated a lot of stuff that Cuckoo needs. They also changed Python2 pip package to install using get-pip.py from universe repository, but I do not recommend this method as you will run into other issues later on.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).